# How to resolve "Retina 4-inch Support" warning

Tags: ios, xcode

I created an iOS application project via Xcode 9.3, but it raise a warning "Retina 4-inch Support".

[image]

I've heard that the warning is raised when supporting 3.5 inch screen devices, but my project support grater than iOS 10.3.
I set Launch Screen File again, but it doesn't resolve. Next, I enabled "Use Asset Catalog..." in Launch Images Source, and then disabled it, but it doesn't.

I don't want to add "Default-568h@2x.png" file because it is unnecessary, what should I do?

Comment: You can either ignore the warning or resolve it by adding the image or (my recommendation) use a launch storyboard rather than launch images

Comment: @Paulw11 I already set a storyboard file as "Launch Screen File", but it's not resolved.

Comment: Make sure you select "Don't use asset catalogs" and select your launch storyboard as the launch screen file